# How to remove a gap below my background image

Tags: css, wpbakery

I am seeing a gap below my image in my header but not sure how to get rid of it. I am using a template and some custom CSS but I cannot see in my inspect what is causing the gap and how to get rid of it. It's easily visible when you view it on a mobile device if you start reducing your browser window. How I can remove this gap?

https://www.thecompleteapproach.co.uk/go/success-to-soar/

CSS:

```
body {
background-image: url(https://www.thecompleteapproach.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/success-to-soar-banner-update.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto;
width: auto!important; overflow-x: hidden!important;
background-attachment: fixed;
}

header{
max-width:100%;
height:100%;
}

.heading-row{
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red , orange);
padding:20px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

section {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

h2{
margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case the aspect ratio of the image does not match the aspect ratio of the wrapping container. As your body changes the aspect ratio you need a flexible solution:

Use: `background-size: cover`
= the image will stretch to the parent wrapper to cover it whole

Note: some parts of the image can be cut in that case. That can become a problem i.e. if you change from desktop view to responsive view to portrait view. In that case you are able to work with different background images. You can do this using `@media` to set different images for different views/devices.

---

**Update to comment question**

The question about what image size should be used for what device is based on two criteria:

1. Needed quality based on the viewport width
2. Desired styling two the special view (i.e. landscape, portrait)

**Needed Quality** means the image file size should be as small as possible (as we want fast loading times) and the resolution of the image is high enough due to (a) width of viewport and (b) resolution of device (as we want to show a sharp and brilliant picture).

That (a) means: on a viewport width of 1.200px (i.e. large desktop screens) the image should have a width off 1.200px. But on smaller screens i.e. a mobile device with a screen width of max 567px the same image only needs to have a width of 567px. So due to this example prepare the same image in two sizes and load the needed image it by using `@media( min-width: 1200px){}` to the different devices.

Actual typical steps to optimize images (= breakpoints) are:

X-Small <576px
Small  ≥576px
Medium ≥768px
Large ≥992px
Extra large ≥1200px
Extra extra large ≥1400px

Note: which breakpoints you serve in your project depends on the project and depends on layout, time, ...

As that is easy the different devices additional have (b) different screen resolutions. Means a modern small device may have a higher screen resolution (ppi = pixel per inch, i.e. a retina display) as an simple desktop monitor (standard: 92dpi). So, as we want to be perfect: to have a sharp image for a modern mobile means to prepare a image with a higher resoltuion (= more pixel = larger image size) than to a bigger desktop screen. This can be done with `@media( min-resolution: 1200px){}`

**Desired Styling** means, that the same image leads not to the same impression/feeling if shown on different devices/viewports. So an image may be great if it is shown on a large screen but on smaller viewports you don't like it because the details are not be shown any more. Or you like to show another image if it is shown in landscape mode on a desktop screen but in a portrait mode on a mobile device.

So, as we want to be perfect once more we chose to show different images on smaller/larger screens and different images in landscape/portrait mode. Even this can be done with `@media(orientation: landscape){}`

**More Information**

That all indeed is slightly complex on the first view. And there are some additional techniques to handle with it. But please note: not all of this perfect image handling is used in any project ... but in practical coding the few projects where are enough resources (time, design power, money the customer likes to sell for the work) to realize most of them are the bests one ;-)

Here are some good explanations to that topic (responsive image handling):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images
https://elad.medium.com/a-complete-guide-for-responsive-images-b13db359c6c7

Comment: I think I need a little help with knowing how to determine what sizes the images shpuld be set based on device

Comment: Updated the answer to your question here in the comment.